# Create temp zip file on Django and delete it after return

Tags: python, django

I'd like to pack many files on my server and make a zip file let people download from my site, once people downloaded, the file will be delete.

I search on stackoverflow, and find some topic but none matches my requirement.

Here is my code:

```
file_name = 'temp.zip'
temp_zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name, 'w')

...do something and get the files...

for file in files:
    temp_zip_file.write(name, arcname=name)

temp_zip_file.close()
response = HttpResponse(open(file_name, 'r').read(), mimetype='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % file_name
return response
```

Where can I add the delete code and make the deletion automatically?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) instead of real file. StringIO is a file-like string buffer.

```
import zipfile
from cStringIO import StringIO

s = StringIO()
temp_zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(s, 'w')
# ...
temp_zip_file.close()

print s.getvalue()
```

so in your case you should do something like this:

```
stream = StringIO()
temp_zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(stream, 'w')

...do something and get the files...

for file in files:
    temp_zip_file.write(name, arcname=name)

temp_zip_file.close()
response = HttpResponse(stream.getvalue(), mimetype='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="temp.zip"'
return response
```

Comment: FWIW, `cStringIO` is faster than `StringIO`, but can't handle Unicode (non-ASCII) characters -- [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html).

Comment: In Python 3 you need `from io import StringIO` instead.